# How do ListFragments work with Loader and Custom Cursor Adapter?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-cursoradapter, android-cursor, android-cursorloader

I have a ListFragment, which loads its data via a loader.
Up to now, I used the build-in R.layout.list_item with SimpleCursorAdapter.
But now, I have to do some custom formatting on each list item and need to use custom list item layout, so I have to convert my ListFragment to work with my custom Cursor Adapter. 
What I don't understand is, how to bind the data, which is loaded asynchronously to my list view. What I have so far is my ListFragment and a GewichtListViewAdapter.

Here is my listfragment:

```
public class GewichtListViewAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

public GewichtListViewAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, boolean autoRequery) {
    super(context, c, autoRequery);
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.listview_item_gewicht, parent, false);
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

    // Find fields to populate in inflated template
    TextView gewichtTextView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.gewichtTextView);
    TextView gemessenAmTextView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.gemessenAmTextView);

    // Extract properties from cursor
    String body = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body"));
    int priority = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("priority"));

    // Populate fields with extracted properties
    long geburtsdatumLong = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(GewichtContract.Columns.GEMESSEN_AM));
    LocalDate geburtsDatumLocalDate = new LocalDate(geburtsdatumLong);
    DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.mediumDate();
    String str = fmt.print(geburtsDatumLocalDate);
    gemessenAmTextView.setText(str);

    double gewichtDouble = cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex(GewichtContract.Columns.GEWICHT));
    BigDecimal gewichtBigDecimal = new BigDecimal(gewichtDouble, MathContext.DECIMAL32);
    gewichtTextView.setText(String.format("%.1f", gewichtBigDecimal));

    }
}
```

This is an excerpt of my ListFragment with Loader:

```
public class GewichtListFragment extends ListFragment implements
    LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>{



@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {

        String[] projection = { GewichtContract.Columns._ID, GewichtContract.Columns.GEMESSEN_AM, GewichtContract.Columns.GEWICHT };

        CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(getActivity(),
        GewichtContract.CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, null);
        return cursorLoader;
        }

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
        adapter.swapCursor(cursor);
        }

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
        adapter.swapCursor(null);
        }




@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }

        // TODO: Change Adapter to display your content
        //setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<DummyContent.DummyItem>(getActivity(),
        //        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, DummyContent.ITEMS));

        String[] uiBindFrom = { GewichtContract.Columns.GEWICHT, GewichtContract.Columns.GEMESSEN_AM };
        int[] uiBindTo = { R.id.gewichtTextView, R.id.gemessenAmTextView };

        getLoaderManager().initLoader(GEWICHT_LIST_LOADER, null, this);

        adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            getActivity(), R.layout.listview_item_gewicht, null, uiBindFrom, uiBindTo,
            CursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        }


}
```

If the simple cursor adapter is used, it is attached in onCreate(). However, I need a reference to the cursor, and I don't have that in onCreate(). Furthermore, at that point the date (to my understanding) isn't loaded yet at this point, so I don't see how I can bind/attach here. 
Can anybody enlighten me how ListFragments, Custom Cursor Adapters and Loaders work together?

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

Creating an empty MatrixCursor and constructing my GewichtListViewAdapter with it in onCreate():

```
        String[] columnNames = {GewichtContract.Columns._ID,
                GewichtContract.Columns.GEMESSEN_AM,
                GewichtContract.Columns.GEWICHT,
                GewichtContract.Columns.HUND_ID};
        MatrixCursor matrixCursor = new MatrixCursor(columnNames);
        gewichtListViewAdapter = new GewichtListViewAdapter(getActivity(), matrixCursor, true);
        setListAdapter(gewichtListViewAdapter);
```

And in onCreateLoader():

```
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {

        String[] projection = { GewichtContract.Columns._ID,
                GewichtContract.Columns.GEMESSEN_AM,
                GewichtContract.Columns.GEWICHT,
                GewichtContract.Columns.HUND_ID
                };

        CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(getActivity(),
        GewichtContract.CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, GewichtContract.Columns.GEMESSEN_AM);
        return cursorLoader;
        }
```

Comment: Interesting...Do you mean GewichtListFragment instead of GewichtListViewAdapter with it in onCreate()?

Comment: @TheOriginalAndroid I believe not. I copy-pasted the code directly from my project, and it works as it is...